# laravel multiple files log viewer using laravel Log-Viewer

Tags: php, laravel, logging, log-viewer

I have **laravel** generate logs for three different purposes.

1. api logs are logged in **Api.log** file.
2. local server logs are logged in **Laravel.log** file.
3. error logs are logged in **error.log** file.

but on the laravel log-viewer I can only see log files that I set in prefix under log-viewer.php file.

How to show all of these files in the Log-Viewer?

Comment: dont be shy in showing us your config now

Comment: What kind of log viewer are you using?

Comment: m using laravel log-viewer package.. for saving request and response of API.
@delboy1978uk
Here is package
https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LogViewer

Comment: Please, add a snippet code!

Comment: I'm developing a log-viewer allowing viewing events from several log files in one view. https://github.com/sevdokimov/log-viewer I hope it can help. If you try it, ask me any questions / feature requests.